# Using nth-child or creating new classes in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I've just started my first project which is building an admin panel. My task is to create HTML and CSS  - sort of a base of design to process further to the back-end developers. 
I was asked to keep CSS simple and classes as descriptive as possible ( could be long ) and to use Bootstrap.

To avoid creating unnecessary classes which could be used once or twice I decided to go with :nth-child since I thought giving new class to each column is too much. Additionally I created few base classes that might be used for adding 0px padding and margin. 
Unfortunately, as I was writing more and more code I've noticed that some CSS code looks like this:

```
.print-history-advanced-search > [class*='col-']:nth-child(5) > .form-group > .form-horizontal > .form-group > [class*='col-']:first-child
```

And it is not a single line.

Additionally, I've noticed that sometimes that when I am making a new class and it has lots of parent elements, I cannot write the CSS selector by its own, but I need to state the parents of the this particular element and put the class at the end, which does not make sense.

Is there any solution I could use to avoid creating classes that are simply used in one or two divs, but also make the CSS code less chaotic and avoid very long names? Or maybe I should just give up on children and nesting and work with just classes?

Thank you for your help!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write good CSS, then I'd suggest the [BEM model](http://getbem.com/) is a good route to go down.

The essentials are;

- No element/selector heirachy
- No use of elements in selectors
- Class based styles only

`BEM` stands for Block, Element, Modifier - which is how your class names are formed. Borrowing an example from their site;

```css
.form { }
.form--theme-xmas { }
.form--simple { }
.form__input { }
.form__submit { }
.form__submit--disabled { }
```

```html
<form class="form form--theme-xmas form--simple">
  <input class="form__input" type="text" />
  <input
    class="form__submit form__submit--disabled"
    type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can see there's a `form` Block, and then a `form__input` and `form__submit` Element, and then a `form__submit--disabled` Modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs I would recommend using `css` preprocessors like `SASS`,`LESS`.
You’ll find that as a website grows, you’ll develop a pretty long, scrolling list of various elements and `CSS` rules. Some of the rules might overlap or override each other eventually (in that case, usually the more specific rule will win).

You can end up with a lot more code than you expected, especially considering the different variations of a rule you need for different browsers and screen sizes.

There are many ways to refactor your `CSS` code to make it easier to navigate and use. Some of the easiest methods are the most effective and have the most mileage. Here are some of the quickest ones:

1. `Keep your spacing uniform`: Maintain the same spacing between rules
   and within declarations throughout your file so that it’s easier to
   read.
2. `Use semantic or “familiar” class/id names:` Instead of using a class
   name like “bottom_menu”, try using the semantic tag “footer”. Or
   when you have an image in your “contact” section, make sure you’re
   using a class on your image like “contact_image”
3. `Keep it DRY` (Don’t Repeat Yourself): Ideally you want to repeat as
   little of your code as possible. Do you find the declaration
   “background-color: #000″ repeated throughout your CSS file? Consider
   typing it once and instead, using multiple selectors on the one
   declaration.
4. Put your tidiness to the test with these tools: Run your CSS through
   CSS Lint or W3C—these will help to parse your CSS file correctly,
   and highlight problem areas. Your `web browser’s developer tools` are
   also extremely useful for pinpointing specific elements on your
   website and using the area as a sandbox to experiment with different
   styles and positioning.
   Have a look [here](http://blog.invisionapp.com/design-css/) for more info

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, we decided not to use SASS this project. But that was my first idea. Either way, very helpful answer. Will  know better in the future!

Comment: @nerwusik it matters a lot